# Each Function and Includes Function isn't working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, lodash

I'm trying to recreate the "includes" method on lodash, using an each function, but it seems that my code isn't working as intended. I'm not sure why when I search for a target that is in the array, what's returned is false instead of true. Here's my code:

```
var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];

function each(set, call) {
    for (var i =0; i<set.length; i++) {
        call(set[i]);
    };
};

function includes(collection, target) {
    each(collection, function(element) {
        if (element === target) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

console.log(includes(array, 1.1));
```

Comment: What actually do you want to accomplish?

Comment: why not `indexOf()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using the return value of `call(set[i])` at all, having `return true` in your lambda function in `includes` will have no effect.

It doesn't make sense to define `includes` in terms of `each` because you will have no way of short-circuiting the logic when you find a value that matches.

Just take advice from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and implement your `includes` as a `for` loop:

```
function includes(collection, target) {
    for(var i = 0; i < collection.length; i += 1) {
        if (collection[i] === target) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

or better yet, use `indexOf`:

```
function includes(collection, target) {
    return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(collection, target) !== -1;
}
```

If you want to define `includes` in terms of a HOF, what would make sense is to define it in terms of `some` or `every`.

Using `some`:

```
function includes(collection, target) {
    return some(collection, function (item) {
        return item === target;
    });
}
```

Using `every`:

```
function includes(collection, target) {
    return !every(collection, function (item) {
        return item !== target;
    });
}
```

Here a simple implementation for `some` and `every` would be:

```
function some(collection, predicate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i += 1) {
        if(predicate(collection[i], i, collection)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function every(collection, predicate) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.lenght; i += 1) {
         if(!predicate(collection[i], i, collection)) {
             return false;
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

They can also be defined in terms of each other (although not at the same time, of course):

```
// Creates the inverse of a function with the same parameters
function negate(func) {
    return function () {
        return !func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

function some(collection, predicate) {
    return !every(collection, negate(predicate));
}

function every(collection, predicate) {
    return !some(collection, negate(predicate));
}
```

Comment: would writing includes in terms of each not be possible? is there any way to change includes or each so that the code will work by writing includes in terms of each?

Comment: @HenryNg As felipsmartins has shown, it is certainly possible, but unnecessarily inefficient. If anything, you should define it in terms of `some` (or if you prefer, `every`). Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

`return true;` returns value of function passed as `each` argument and not value of `includes` function.

This is how this should look like:

```
function includes(set, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i<set.length; i++) {
        if (set[i] === target) return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `indexOf`.

```
var array = [1.1,1.3,2.3,2.5,3.1,3.5];
function include(arr, i){
    if(arr.indexOf(i)==-1) return false;
    return true;
}    
console.log(include(array,1.1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause boolean value is returned to closer caller (each() ) rather the parent caller (includes()). It works:

```
function includes(collection, target) {
    var retval = false;
    each(collection, function(element) {
        if (element === target) {
            retval = true;
        }
    });
    return retval;
}
```

However, is a lot better avoid computer a whole sequence:

```
//it works with String and Array objects
function inSequence(searchValue, target){
    if (-1 != target.indexOf(searchValue)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So instead call includes() let's call inSequence():

```
inSequence(1.1, array); //returns true
```

Comment: thanks! i don't know why it says illegal break statement, but when you change the code to return retval = true, it works!

Comment: @HenryNg "break" statement was a type(not make a sense on non loop)... but I think JLRishe is a lot better. Using indexOf and evoiding computer unnecessarily a whole sequence.